# Maven mvn without standalone just plugin

Tags: maven

How to issue a mvn command (for example to install an oracle driver) when standalone maven installation is not installed because I'm using the plugin in eclipse neon?

Answer (score 0):

With `Run as -> Maven build` you can run arbitrary Maven commands. Just leave out the `mvn` at the beginning.